# Fetching bound records from mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to sort by 'greater than a certain time' in mySQL and am using prepared statements.

The query works when put directly into the database but not when in a prepared statement. I am getting no errors whatsoever.

```
$timeSinceFirstMark="2015-04-20";
$markRemain = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT (100-COUNT(id)) FROM markers WHERE date_create > ?");
$markRemain->bind_param('s', $timeSinceFirstMark);
$markRemain->execute();
$markRemain->store_result();
$markRemain->bind_result($markRemainCount);
echo $markRemainCount;
```

Comment: It looks like it could be a simple missing quote problem.  What is the exact sql you put directly into the database?

Comment: @paqogomez Missing quote where? You don't put quotes around a placeholder in a prepared statement.

Comment: hey thanks for getting back to me.  SELECT 100-COUNT(id) from markers where date_create > '2015-03-30'.

Comment: @Barmar's right.  How about `Count` being an aggregate function, but you're not grouping by anything?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the prepared statement should work as you wrote it. I looked around for other questions about using dates and times in prepared statements, and they all work fine when the PHP variable is a string with the date and time.

Comment: @paqogomez If you don't group by anything, you get the total count in the table.

Comment: @Barmar strike two.  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: BTW, unless the `id` column can contain nulls, and you don't want to count them, you should use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: ok thanks for the tips. Ill play around with it any let you guys know what works.

Answer (score 0):

After you bind a result variable using `bind_result()` you need to fetch a row using `fetch()`, which will assign values from SQL to these variables.

```
$markRemain = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT (100-COUNT(id)) FROM markers WHERE date_create > ?");
$markRemain->bind_param('s', $timeSinceFirstMark);
$markRemain->execute();
$markRemain->store_result();
$markRemain->bind_result($markRemainCount);

$markRemain->fetch();

echo $markRemainCount;
```